# Unity OnControllerColliderHit detecting not detecting correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to teleport the character when they touch a cube, but for some reason, it prints the message that it the collision is being detected, but the character's position is not changing. It works for another scenario that is almost exactly the same, but even if I put this in another script, it does not teleport the character. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class othercollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        if (hit.gameObject.name == "teleportcube")
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-3184.53f, 20.35f, -171.585f);
            Debug.Log("Collision detected");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the script that has something similar working:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
public class detectcollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tplocation1;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject entranceloc;
    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        //This if statement does Debug.Log the message and it also changes the player's position.
        if (hit.gameObject.name == "trigger")
        {
            Debug.Log("triggered");
            gameObject.transform.position = tplocation1.transform.position;
            Thread.Sleep(7);
            Application.Quit();
        }
        //This if statement does not change the player's position, but Debug.Logs the teleporting message.
        if (hit.gameObject.name == "entrance")
        {
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-3184.53f, 20.35f, -171.585f);
            Debug.Log("teleporting...");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this script is attached to player (root)? Maybe it's a child of a player and you change just the childs position, not the player (root)?

Comment: Yes, the script is a child of the player, but this problem only seems to happen in this type of if-statement.

Comment: have you tried setting player.transform.position ?

Comment: Everything else in the script is working. The only thing that has problems is when I try to change the player's position. In the above script, this worked, but for some reason, when I try to use it in this if-statement, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the Vector3 beforehand as a variable or a temporary variable and then assign it to the position. If you did then maybe the values that you have entered are out of boundary somewhy, but that's unlikely, try changing them.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a simple code example to make your solution more clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).